# Regular expression for maximum digits excluding comma

Tags: asp.net

I have the below regular expression:

```
ValidationExpression="[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*"
```

It allows numbers in the format: 12,2345 or 231,23454

Now I want to include a condition that will on the whole allow only 7 digits max excluding 
comma. 
**The below is the modified code**

The below is in the item template

I also have a radio button in item template

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbText" CssClass="someclass" MaxLength="11"
                                          %>'></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*" ID="ValComp" runat="server" CssClass="asdf"
    ControlToValidate="tbMileage" Text="*" Enabled="false" Display="Dynamic"/>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvalMileage" runat="server" CssClass="adsf" Text="*" Display="Dynamic">
</asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ClientValidationFunction="functionName" 
    runat="server" CssClass="asd" Text="*" Display="Dynamic">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Since I want to validate the radio button checked corresponding textbox in repeater the below is the code I have written

```
var selText = $(".Class1 input[type=radio]:checked").closest(".Class1").find(".subClassText input[type=text]").val();
alert('Hi');
if (selText.replace(",", "").length <= 7) {
    args.IsValid = true;
}
else {
    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

The alert fires twice and based on args is False i have a popup that is firing twice

Thanks.

Comment: When faced with a problem, many people say to themselfs: "I can solve this using Regular Expressions". Now they have 2 problems.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are not good at this problem, but if you limit your input to a maximum of one comma this expression will fit:

```
([0-9]{0,0}[,]?[0-9]{0,7})|([0-9]{0,1}[,]?[0-9]{0,6})|([0-9]{0,2}[,]?[0-9]{0,5})|([0-9]{0,3}[,]?[0-9]{0,4})|([0-9]{0,4}[,]?[0-9]{0,3})|([0-9]{0,5}[,]?[0-9]{0,2})|([0-9]{0,6}[,]?[0-9]{0,1})|([0-9]{0,7}[,]?[0-9]{0,0})
```

You will recognize that this problem is not well suited for regular expression as this expression is fixed to your maximum of 7.

Comment: I thoug regex would be easy to modify according to my req. is it better to use some javascript/jquery to remove special characters and set max length for numbers only, can you provide me some references

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/303z9x0x.aspx) control with client-side validation like this:

ASPX code:

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
           ControlToValidate="YourControlNameHere"
           ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidation"
           OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
           ErrorMessage="Invalid number." />
```

JavaScript (uses jQuery):

```
function ClientValidation(source, arguments)
{
    var inputText = arguments.Value;
    var expression = /^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$/;
    if (expression.test(inputText) && inputText.replace(",", "").length <= 7) {
        arguments.IsValid = true;
    }
    else {
        arguments.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

C# code behind:

```
public void ServerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    string inputText = args.Value;
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d+(,\d+)*$");
    if (regex.IsMatch(inputText) && inputText.Replace(",", "").Length <= 7)
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i get it without custom validator, because i have to validate all this inside a repeater, just a regular expression would be fine even it is bigger

Comment: @phanikumar - It shouldn't be a problem to use a CustomValidator inside a repeater.  You were using a RegularExpressionValidator control before, right?  You should be able to use a CustomValidator in the same way.

Comment: yes, i have included customvalidator in item template. I have implemented the Client validation function. now the validation function fires twice, if i put an alert i could see it. I have modifeid my code above, please look at it